# DDD C# - Em qual camada devo implementar a parte de exportação de Dados

Tags: c#, design-pattern, ddd

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# e WPF, com diversos cadastros como Clientes, Fornecedores, Produtos, etc. Estou utilizando o conceito de DDD e estou com uma dúvida à respeito de como implementar um módulo de exportação de dados. Precisarei exportar dados e os arquivos ficarão no formato xml, csv e txt.

Em qual camada eu implemento esse módulo? Alguém possui algum exemplo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu colocaria a leitura e escrita do arquivo no Infra.Data e colocaria a regra de montagem dos dados no Domain.

Comment: No caso, eu criaria Interfaces semelhantes às do CRUD com o EntityFramework?

Comment: Poderia ser nesse caso.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica joaoeduardorf!!

Answer (score 2):

Assumo que esse módulo de relatório vai utilizar alguns Frameworks para gerar esses Excel (exemplo EPPlus) e PDF (exemplo ITextSharp), logo é interessante você criar isso na camada de **CrossCutting** para desacoplar esses Frameworks da sua camada de Application. Se um dia um desses Framework ficar obsoleto ou você quiser fazer outro, a minha camada de regra de negócio não sera alterada.

A camada de CrossCutting serve exatamente para módulos do sistemas que influenciam outros módulos, como camada de persistência, serviços, etc. Como exemplo de coisas feita na camada de CrossCutting são módulo de segurança, sistema de LOG, e também para caso de seus relatórios.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, o "correto"(dependendo do caso), seria colocar no Application, pois teoricamente, você tem que passar no domain para exportar dados **consistentes** e a camada que tem as regras de negocio que **consiste** os dados é o Dominio.
Entao o normal seria ter essa reponsabilidade na camada de Serviço(não serviço de dominio), não na camada de dados, nem na camada de negocio(dominio), dependendo de como vc vai exportar poderia estar ate na apresentação.

se vc não entendeu ou quiser mais detalhes so chamar...

ps: se quiser saber mais afundo sobre essas questoes de onde colocar e como fazer recomendo o [implementando domain drive desing do Vaughn Vernon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321834577)... abrs